# image of sum is a subset of sum of images

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have linear transformations $f:V\to W$ and $g:V\to W$. How can I prove the following

$Im(f+g)\subset Im(f) + Im(g)$

I understand that if I have some vector $y$ which belongs to $Im(f+g)$ that it also belongs to $Im(f) + Im(g)$, but I don't really see how it proves that it's a subset.

Answer (score 1):

Let us take some $y\in \text{Im}(f+g)$.

So there exists $x\in V$ such that $(f+g)x=y$

By linearity,

$$ y=f(x)+g(x) \in \text{Im}f + \text{Im}g $$

And the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f, g : V \rightarrow W$

$$\text{Im}f = \{f(x):x\in V\}$$

$$\text{Im}g = \{g(y):y\in V\}$$

$$\text{Im}(f+g) = \{(f+g)(x):x\in V\} = \{f(x)+g(x):x\in V\}$$

$$\text{Im}f + \text{Im}g = \{f(x) + g(y):x\in V, y\in V\}$$

So, you can see how some vectors goes missing in Im$(f+g)$ (that is unless it spans the entire space of (Im$f$ + Im$g$)). To get Im$(f+g)$ from (Im$f$ + Im$g$), you would have to plug in $x=y$ in the definition of (Im$f$ + Im$g$), which is a constraint and hence the space is smaller. (Im$f$ + Im$g$) on the other hand has no such constraints.

Hence,

$$\text{Im}(f+g) \subseteq \text{Im}f + \text{Im}g$$

Comment: This answer is really helpful. Thanks!